# AFNetworking 2.0 certificate not read

Tags: ios7, afnetworking-2

I use the code to read JSON data:

```
[[DVAPIManager sharedManager] setUsername:user andPassword:pass];

NSLog(@"Using %d pinned certificates", [[DVAPIManager sharedManager].securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates count]);
[[DVAPIManager sharedManager] GET:@"/areas" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

but the NSLong that i have for debugging reasons gives:Using 0 pinned certificates

i have already copy apache.cer file to the project and also in my singleton class file:

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if(!self)
        return nil;

    self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
    AFSecurityPolicy *mySecurityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [mySecurityPolicy setSSLPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];


    [self  setSecurityPolicy:mySecurityPolicy];


    return self;
}
```

when i run, i get the error:

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)

Any idea why can not GET the JSON data and why the system can not read my.cer file?

When i try to read the .cer file manually

```
[mySecurityPolicy setPinnedCertificates:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"apache.cer", nil]];
```

it crashes!!

Comment: Please fix your title, formatting and spelling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with adding this code in my singleton class in order to read the certificate file:

```
NSString* fileRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"apache" ofType:@"cer"];

NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileRoot];

self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
AFSecurityPolicy *mySecurityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
[mySecurityPolicy setSSLPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];

[mySecurityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
[mySecurityPolicy setPinnedCertificates:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:certData, nil]];
```

probably the default read of .cer files it's not working, you have to do it manually (like in the code above)

Comment: FYI, this implementation is actually skipping SSL pinning altogether since you setAllowInvalidCertificates to YES.

Comment: @drewag Do you have a solution for the issue without skipping SSL pinning?

Comment: Yes, I got it working for my own certificate without having to resort to allowing invalid certificates. My add my solution the question itself, but in short, I manually loaded the certificate and set it on the existing security policy (after setting it to AFSSLPinningModePublicKey).

Comment: This does not fix anything (for me)

Answer (score 4):

I got my certificate working by manually loading in the certificate:

```
- (void)setupSSL
{
    self.securityPolicy.SSLPinningMode = AFSSLPinningModePublicKey;
    NSString *sslPublicKeyPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mydomain" ofType:@"cer"];
    NSData *sslPublicKey = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sslPublicKeyPath];
    [self.securityPolicy setPinnedCertificates:@[
        sslPublicKey
    ]];
}
```

I generated my key from my pem with the following:

```
openssl x509 -in mydomain.pem -out mydomain.cer -outform der
```